# Is it possible to find object's class in the list of objects?

Tags: c#

I've got a list of objects = { obj1,obj2,obj3 }

Every class of the objects is inherited from the same interface

```
interface IObjects
class Obj1:IObjects
class Obj2:IObjects
class Obj3:IObjects
```

And I want to find object of Obj1 class for examp. 
How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so by:

```
var listOfObject1s = objects.Where(o => o is Obj1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(obj.GetType() == typeof(Obj1))
{
    // obj is an Obj1!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the list and check for

```
item is Obj1
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq method:

```
IObjects[] objList = new IObjects[] { obj1,obj2,obj3 };
obj1 o1 = objList.Where(o => o.GetType() = typeof(Obj1)).First();
```

Comment: this throws an exception if one object is `null`

Answer (score 1):

Call GetType() on your object. [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx). Hope this helps